# Does a WCF service always use an svc file?

Tags: wcf, asmx

I'm converting my asmx web services to WCF. Does this inherently mean the file type needs to change from .asmx to .svc?

Comment: No, WCF services can be self-hosted without any `.svc` files. If you're using WAS, however, I think it's required.

Comment: @ta.speot.is : So I can convert my existing web services with .asmx files into WCF without changing the asmx file types? Also what does WAS stand for?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733109.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every WCF service needs to have a host process : a windows service,IIS or any other .NET program. This host will create an instance of the System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost (or any custom System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase) and will manage the service configurations, behaviors, channels.

However, when a service is hosted in IIS it behaves a little bit differently. By default, we need to create a physical file with .svc extension. It's a pure IIS requirement. There's a module within IIS that handles the .svc file type. This file is just a declaration of the service type and optionnaly service host factory type.

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory" Service="MyFamousCalculatorService" CodeBehind="MyFamousCalculatorService.svc.cs" %>
```

Since WCF 4.0, we can create and deploy services in IIS without a physical .svc file.This can be done using the `serviceActivations` configuration in the `system.serviceModel` configuration section.

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="MyFamousCalculatorService.svc" service="MyFamousCalculatorService"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have much experience with `serviceActivations`, is there any compelling benefit to it over a `.svc` file? I've had a look at MSDN and it seems to me that `serviceActions` is just another way of achieving pretty much the same thing that a `.svc` file does.